# SpringBatch App Using JDBC for Reading is Failing to Start

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have something very similar to the code below (I had to do some obfiscation). I am getting an Application Failed to Start error. Code not shown are datasource bean and spring boot application class. When I put breakpoints in and all run in debug, all beans appear to be created except the Job and Step bean, which seem to be skipped over entirely. I am not sure how to diagnose further. Seems to be some Spring Magic issues.  Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Here is the exception:

2020-08-23 11:26:50.264  INFO 12195 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-08-23 11:26:50.265  INFO 12195 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.31]
2020-08-23 11:26:50.382  INFO 12195 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-08-23 11:26:50.383  INFO 12195 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2276 ms
2020-08-23 11:26:57.552  WARN 12195 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'databaseCursorStep' defined in class path resource [/com/configuration/BatchConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'databaseCursorStep' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader<com.dto.StuffDto>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=databaseCursorItemReader)}
2020-08-23 11:26:57.572  INFO 12195 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-08-23 11:26:57.603  INFO 12195 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-08-23 11:26:57.908 ERROR 12195 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Parameter 0 of method databaseCursorStep in com.configuration.BatchConfig required a bean of type 'org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=databaseCursorItemReader)

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader' in your configuration.

Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:46088', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1

Here is the code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfig {

@Autowired
public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;


private static final String GET_DATA =
    "SELECT " +
            "stuffA, " +
            "stuffB, " +
            "FROM STUFF_TABLE " +
            "ORDER BY stuffA ASC";

@Bean
public ItemReader<StuffDto> itemReader(DataSource dataSource) {
    return new JdbcCursorItemReaderBuilder<StuffDto>()
        .name("cursorItemReader")
        .dataSource(dataSource)
        .sql(GET_DATA)
        .rowMapper(new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(StuffDto.class))
        .build();
}

@Bean
    ItemProcessor<StuffDto, StuffDto> databaseXmlItemProcessor() {
        return new QueryLoggingProcessor();
    }

@Bean
    public ItemWriter<StuffDto> databaseCursorItemWriter() {
        return new LoggingItemWriter();
    }

@Bean
    public Step databaseCursorStep(@Qualifier("databaseCursorItemReader") ItemReader<StuffDto> reader,
                                   @Qualifier("databaseCursorItemWriter") ItemWriter<StuffDto> writer,
                                   StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("databaseCursorStep")
            .<StuffDto, StuffDto>chunk(1)
            .reader(reader)
            .writer(writer)
            .build();
}

@Bean
    public Job databaseCursorJob(@Qualifier("databaseCursorStep") Step exampleJobStep,
                                 JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("databaseCursorJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .flow(exampleJobStep)
                .end()
                .build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Qualifier Bean name is `itemReader` not `databaseCursorItemReader`. Either change the method name or change to `databaseCursorStep(@Qualifier("itemReader")`

```
@Bean
public Step databaseCursorStep(@Qualifier("itemReader") ItemReader<StuffDto> reader,
                                   @Qualifier("databaseCursorItemWriter") ItemWriter<StuffDto> writer,
                                   StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("databaseCursorStep")
            .<StuffDto, StuffDto>chunk(1)
            .reader(reader)
            .writer(writer)
            .build();

     }

@Bean
public ItemReader<StuffDto> itemReader(DataSource dataSource) {
    return new JdbcCursorItemReaderBuilder<StuffDto>()
        .name("cursorItemReader")
        .dataSource(dataSource)
        .sql(GET_DATA)
        .rowMapper(new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(StuffDto.class))
        .build();
}
```